# Styling video tag in WinJS

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime, winjs

I am trying to change the progress bar color of a video tag when playing a video in a Windows 8 HTML5 App, but I can not find which Css property I have to modify. Also, I can not find documentation about that.

Comment: I have tried via css with #myvideonode::-ms-fill-lower{
    background-color:red;
} but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own DOM nodes, and by using the exposed methods of the video tag spec, you can mimic and expand on the default functionality.

Comment: I edited the question sorry, I only want to change de bar color of default video view :)